# Saving data to multiple tables from a single json POST-request on Ruby Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello I am new to both Ruby and Rails, but I wanted to create a simle MVC-application. The task at hand is to have the system accepting POST-requests with a JSON-formatted string and then save them into their respective tables.

Here is the controller:

```
require 'json'
require 'net/http'
class ParameterController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token #I worry about the security later
    def create
        @temperature=Temperature.create(params.dig(:parameter,:temp))
        @humidity=Humidity.create(params.dig(:parameter,:humidity))
        @rainfall=Rainfall.create(params.dig(:parameter,:rainfall))
        @wind=Wind.create(params.dig(:parameter,:windspeed), params.dig(:parameter,:winddir))
        
        
    end   
end
```

Models:

```
class Temperature < ApplicationRecord
    def initialize(value)
        @value = value
    end
    
end
```

Same seen in other parameters with one exception

```
class Wind < ApplicationRecord
    @value
    @angle
    def initialize(value,angle)
        @value=value
        @decimal=angle
    end
    
end
```

And the DB-migration

```
class CreateTemperatures < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :temperatures do |t|
      t.decimal :value
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I've tried various ways to save those parameters to database, but keep getting error messages when I try to send those requests. Among them is `"NoMethodError (undefined method` []' for nil:NilClass)"`. There are many things that seem to be automated in Rails, although I've made my mistake of getting on with it without having enough experience in Ruby. I just wanted to make a very simple app.

EDIT: As requested

```
activerecord (5.1.7) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:414:in `clear_transaction_record_state'
activerecord (5.1.7) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:328:in `ensure in rollback_active_record_state!'
activerecord (5.1.7) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:328:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
activerecord (5.1.7) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:307:in `save'
activerecord (5.1.7) lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:42:in `save'
activerecord (5.1.7) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:34:in `create'
app/controllers/parameter_controller.rb:7:in `create'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:186:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:131:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:252:in `process_action'
activerecord (5.1.7) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:124:in `process'
actionview (5.1.7) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:189:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:253:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:31:in `serve'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `each'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `serve'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:844:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:40:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
activerecord (5.1.7) lib/active_record/migration.rb:556:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59:in `call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:30:in `block in call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `catch'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
railties (5.1.7) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:706:in `handle_request'
puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:476:in `process_client'
puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'
puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: Can you show a complete stack trace?

Comment: Added to the question.